# How to use groupBy in sparkR to count keeping other columns as it is?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

In sparkR i need to count the number of occurrences of col `STORE` in data frame `df3`

```
>df3 <- select(df_1,"DC_NAME","STORE", "ITEM_DESC","ITEM")

>head(df3)
 DC_NAME STORE                    ITEM_DESC      ITEM
1  Kerala  1216 Nambisan Ghee 200 Ml Pet Jar 100050222
2  Kerala  1216 Nambisan Ghee 100 ml Pet Jar 100149022
3  Kerala  1216  Nambisan Ghee 50 ml Pet Jar 100149024
4  Kerala  1219 Nambisan Ghee 500 Ml Pet Jar 100050210
5  Kerala  1219 Nambisan Ghee 200 Ml Pet Jar 100050222
6  Kerala  1219  Nambisan Ghee 50 ml Pet Jar 100149024

For counting number times column STORE occurs, i used the code,
df_3 <- groupBy(df_3,"STORE") %>% count()
STORE count
1  1216     3
2  1219     3
3  3154     1
4  3049     3
5  1990     3
6  3107     4
```

But i need the result in this form, including columns `'DC_NAME, ITEM_DESC, ITEM'` . Is there any code.

```
DC_NAME STORE                    ITEM_DESC      ITEM    count
1  Kerala  1216 Nambisan Ghee 200 Ml Pet Jar 100050222   3
2  Kerala  1216 Nambisan Ghee 100 ml Pet Jar 100149022   3
3  Kerala  1216  Nambisan Ghee 50 ml Pet Jar 100149024   3
4  Kerala  1219 Nambisan Ghee 500 Ml Pet Jar 100050210   3
5  Kerala  1219 Nambisan Ghee 200 Ml Pet Jar 100050222   3
6  Kerala  1219  Nambisan Ghee 50 ml Pet Jar 100149024   3
```

Comment: Just `join` aggregate with the input. Or use window functions with unbounded window.

Comment: Yea in `join` it can be achieved,  but in R it can be achieved using `group_by`. Like that will it can be done using sparkR

Comment: Nope. `join` or  window functions are the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid `join` you can use a window function with unbounded range. Assuming your data has a following structure:

```
df <- structure(list(DC_NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = " Kerala ", class = "factor"), 
    STORE = c(1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1219L, 1219L, 1219L),
    ITEM_DESC = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c(" Nambisan Ghee 100 ml Pet Jar", 
    " Nambisan Ghee 200 Ml Pet Jar", " Nambisan Ghee 500 Ml Pet Jar", 
    "  Nambisan Ghee 50 ml Pet Jar"), class = "factor"), ITEM = c(100050222L, 
    100149022L, 100149024L, 100050210L, 100050222L, 100149024L
    )), .Names = c("DC_NAME", "STORE", "ITEM_DESC", "ITEM"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 ", "6 "))
```

- create Spark `DataFrame` using **Hive Context**:

  ```
  hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
  sdf <- createDataFrame(hiveContext, df)
  ```
- register it as a temporary table:

  ```
  registerTempTable(sdf, "sdf")
  ```
- prepare query:

  ```
  query <- "SELECT *, SUM(1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY STORE
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) AS count FROM sdf"
  ```
- execute it using `sql` function:

  ```
  sql(hiveContext, query)
  ```